Errors when adding an L3 cache in gem5 config script
I was just starting to learn gem5 and i was trying to add an L3 cache on top of the two-level cache in the official tutorial.
These are the L2 cache and L3 cache i wrote according to the tutorial:
class L2Cache(Cache):
    """Simple L2 Cache with default values"""

    # Default parameters
    size = "256kB"
    assoc = 8
    tag_latency = 20
    data_latency = 20
    response_latency = 20
    mshrs = 20
    tgts_per_mshr = 12

    SimpleOpts.add_option("--l2_size", help=f"L2 cache size. Default: {size}")

    def __init__(self, opts=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not opts or not opts.l2_size:
            return
        self.size = opts.l2_size

    def connectCPUSideBus(self, bus):
        self.cpu_side = bus.mem_side_ports

    def connectMemSideBus(self, bus):
        self.mem_side = bus.cpu_side_ports

class L3Cache(Cache):
    """Simple L3 Cache with default values"""

    # Default parameters
    size = "4MB"
    assoc = 16
    tag_latency = 40
    data_latency = 40
    response_latency = 40
    mshrs = 40
    tgts_per_mshr = 16

    SimpleOpts.add_option("--l3_size", help=f"L3 cache size. Default: {size}")

    def __init__(self, opts=None):
        super().__init__()
        if not opts or not opts.l3_size:
            return
        self.size = opts.l3_size

    def connectCPUSideBus(self, bus):
        self.cpu_side = bus.mem_side_ports

    def connectMemSideBus(self, bus):
        self.mem_side = bus.cpu_side_ports

I assume there are two ways to connect the L2 cache to L3 cache:

Directly connect L2 ports to L3 ports.
Declare an "l3" bus in between L2 and L3. This bus seems to be L2XBar since i did not find any other materials.

Following 2:
# Create a simple CPU
system.cpu = DerivO3CPU()

# Create an L1 instruction and data cache
system.cpu.icache = L1ICache(args)
system.cpu.dcache = L1DCache(args)

system.cpu.icache.connectCPU(system.cpu)
system.cpu.dcache.connectCPU(system.cpu)


# Create a memory bus, a coherent crossbar, in this case
system.l2bus = L2XBar()
system.l3bus = L2XBar() # if commented, got abortion errors!!!

# connect
system.cpu.icache.connectBus(system.l2bus)
system.cpu.dcache.connectBus(system.l2bus)

system.l2cache = L2Cache(args)
system.l2cache.connectCPUSideBus(system.l2bus)
system.l3cache = L3Cache(args)

system.membus = SystemXBar()
system.l3cache.connectCPUSideBus(system.l3bus)
system.l2cache.connectMemSideBus(system.l3bus)
system.l3cache.connectMemSideBus(system.membus)

# create the interrupt controller for the CPU
system.cpu.createInterruptController()
system.cpu.interrupts[0].pio = system.membus.mem_side_ports
system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_requestor = system.membus.cpu_side_ports
system.cpu.interrupts[0].int_responder = system.membus.mem_side_ports

# Connect the system up to the membus
system.system_port = system.membus.cpu_side_ports

This gives the following error.
src/mem/dram_interface.cc:690: warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
src/base/statistics.hh:279: warn: One of the stats is a legacy stat. Legacy stat is a stat that does not belong to any statistics::Group. Legacy stat is deprecated.
system.remote_gdb: Listening for connections on port 7000
Beginning simulation!
src/sim/simulate.cc:199: info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
gem5.opt: src/mem/mem_ctrl.cc:701: bool gem5::memory::MemCtrl::addToReadQueue(gem5::PacketPtr, unsigned int, gem5::memory::MemInterface*): Assertion `!readQueueFull(1)' failed.
Program aborted at tick 428000
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem515print_backtraceEv+0x30)[0x5625aab171c0]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem512abortHandlerEi+0x4e)[0x5625aab3c39e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x14420)[0x7f38a9bf3420]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb)[0x7f38a94ea00b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b)[0x7f38a94c9859]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x22729)[0x7f38a94c9729]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x33fd6)[0x7f38a94dafd6]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem56memory7MemCtrl14addToReadQueueEPNS_6PacketEjPNS0_12MemInterfaceE+0xc67)[0x5625aa4393b7]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem56memory7MemCtrl13recvTimingReqEPNS_6PacketE+0x509)[0x5625aa440fd9]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem512CoherentXBar13recvTimingReqEPNS_6PacketEs+0x49c)[0x5625aa411ffc]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem511RequestPort13sendTimingReqEPNS_6PacketE+0x2f)[0x5625aa53432f]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem59BaseCache19sendMSHRQueuePacketEPNS_4MSHRE+0x583)[0x5625aa5311e3]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem55Cache19sendMSHRQueuePacketEPNS_4MSHRE+0x16f)[0x5625aa54b2ef]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem59BaseCache19CacheReqPacketQueue18sendDeferredPacketEv+0xd9)[0x5625aa523629]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem510EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0xc2)[0x5625aab2a0f2]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem59doSimLoopEPNS_10EventQueueE+0x70)[0x5625aab58050]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN4gem58simulateEm+0x29b)[0x5625aab586db]
build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x1dda562)[0x5625ab862562]
build/X86/gem5.opt(+0x8d9c96)[0x5625aa361c96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(+0x2a8748)[0x7f38a9eaa748]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x8dd8)[0x7f38a9c7ff48]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x8fb)[0x7f38a9dcce4b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x94)[0x7f38a9eaa124]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(+0x74d6d)[0x7f38a9c76d6d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7d86)[0x7f38a9c7eef6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x8fb)[0x7f38a9dcce4b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x42)[0x7f38a9dcd1d2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1f)[0x7f38a9dcd5bf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(+0x1cfc01)[0x7f38a9dd1c01]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(+0x25f547)[0x7f38a9e61547]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(+0x74d6d)[0x7f38a9c76d6d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x12fd)[0x7f38a9c7846d]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
For more info on how to address this issue, please visit https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/common-errors/ 

Aborted (core dumped)

However, if following 1:
# Create a memory bus, a coherent crossbar, in this case
system.l2bus = L2XBar()
system.l3bus = L2XBar()  # if commented, got abortion errors!!!

# connect
system.cpu.icache.connectBus(system.l2bus)
system.cpu.dcache.connectBus(system.l2bus)

system.l2cache = L2Cache(args)
system.l2cache.connectCPUSideBus(system.l2bus)
system.l3cache = L3Cache(args)

system.membus = SystemXBar()
system.l2cache.mem_side = system.l3cache.cpu_side
system.l3cache.connectMemSideBus(system.membus)

The weirdest thing happened. If I comment out the system.l3bus = L2XBar(), I still got the same abortion error (But i already don't use the l3bus anymore!). However, if I keep the line, i get the exact same output as this post:
Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: No dot file generated. Please install pydot to generate the dot file and pdf.
src/mem/dram_interface.cc:690: warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
src/base/statistics.hh:279: warn: One of the stats is a legacy stat. Legacy stat is a stat that does not belong to any statistics::Group. Legacy stat is deprecated.
system.remote_gdb: Listening for connections on port 7000
src/mem/coherent_xbar.cc:140: warn: CoherentXBar system.l3bus has no snooping ports attached!
src/base/statistics.hh:1175: fatal: fatal condition (_x <= 0) || (_y <= 0) occurred: Storage sizes must be positive
Memory Usage: 644212 KBytes

And the answer over there does not offer any help. Could anyone please tell me how to resolve this? Or how can I customize the se.py script so it has three levels of cache. Appreciate any help!

After taking a closer look at the error message
gem5.opt: src/mem/mem_ctrl.cc:701: bool gem5::memory::MemCtrl::addToReadQueue(gem5::PacketPtr, unsigned int, gem5::memory::MemInterface*): Assertion `!readQueueFull(1)' failed

I found that this has something to do with the read queue and write queue. More on this can be found here.
Therefore, simply add the following to the config script, and both ways would work for my original code:
system.mem_ctrl.dram.read_buffer_size = 512  # Number of entries in read queue
system.mem_ctrl.dram.write_buffer_size =512  # Number of entries in write queue

